# Changing a list of values in Awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to change values in the following list:

```
A 0.702
B 0.868
C 3.467
D 2.152
```

If the second column is less than 0.5 I would like to change to -2, between 0.5-1 to -1, between 1-1.5 to 1 and if > 1.5 then to 2.

When I try the following:

```
awk '$2<0.9 || $2>2' | awk '{if ($2 < 0.5) print $1,-2;}{if($2>0.5 || $2<1) print $1,-1;}{if($2>1 || $2<1.5) print $1,1;}{if($2>2) print $1,2;}'
```

I get the following:

```
A -1
A 1
B -1
B 1
C 1
C 2
D 1
D 2
```

I know I am missing something but for the life of me I can't figure out what - any help gratefully recieved.

Comment: please update the question to show the (correct) expected result; also update the question to clarify the test ranges, as currently written both `1` and `1.5` are 'included' in two different ranges ... it's hard to tell from the current description which range end points are inclusive (`<=` / `>=`) or exclusive (`<` / `>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple if statements and the current value can match multiple statements, you can print multiple outputs.

If you only want to print the output of the first match, you would have to prevent running the if statements that follow.

You can use a single awk and define non overlapping matches with greater than and `&&` lower than.

Note that using only `>` and `<` you will not for example 0.5

```
awk '{
  if($2 < 0.5) print($1, -2)
  if($2 > 0.5 && $2<1) print($1,-1)
  if($2 > 1 && $2<1.5) print($1, 1)
  if($2 > 1.5) print($1 ,2)
}
' file
```

Output

```
A -1
B -1
C 2
D 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Another. Replace `<`s with `<=`s where needed:

```
$ awk '{
    if($2<0.5)      # from low to higher sets the lower limit
        $2=-2
    else if($2<1)   # so only upper limit needs to be tested
        $2=-1
    else if($2<1.5)
        $2=1
    else 
        $2=2
}1' file
```

Output:

```
A -1
B -1
C 2
D 2
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples only. Adding one more solution with using ternary operators for condition checking(for Fun :) ).

`awk '{print (NF?($2>1.5?($1 OFS 2):($2>1?($1 OFS 1):($2>0.5?($1 OFS "-1"):($1 OFS "-2")))):"")}' Input_file`

***Better readable form*** of above `awk` code. Since its a one-liner so breaking it up into multi form for better readability here.

```
awk '
{
  print \
(\
  NF\
  ?\
    ($2>1.5\
    ?\
      ($1 OFS 2)\
    :\
      ($2>1\
      ?\
        ($1 OFS 1)\
      :\
        ($2>0.5\
        ?\
          ($1 OFS "-1")\
        :\
          ($1 OFS "-2")\
        )\
      )\
     )\
  :\
    ""\
)
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be using ternary operators to perform conditions and accordingly printing values(since its happening in `print` function).

Answer (score 2):

Probably overkill for your needs but here's a data-driven approach using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and +/-inf:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    range["-inf"][0.5] = -2
    range[0.5][1]      = -1
    range[1][1.5]      =  1
    range[1.5]["+inf"] =  2
}
{
    val = ""
    for ( beg in range ) {
        for ( end in range[beg] ) {
            if ( (beg+0 < $2) && ($2 <= end+0) ) {
                val = range[beg][end]
            }
        }
    }

    print $1, val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A -1
B -1
C 2
D 2
```

I'm assuming above that "between" excludes the start of the range but includes the end of it. You could make it slightly more efficient with:

```
for ( beg in range ) {
    if ( beg+0 < $2 ) {
        for ( end in range[beg] ) {
            if ( $2 <= end+0 ) {
                val = range[beg][end]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I just like having the range comparison all on 1 line and there's only 1 end for every begin so it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: i fully concur - it's truly an overkill of multi-dimensional arrays for a task that could be done in a portable, array-less, one-liner

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 : new equation should cover nearly all scenarios :

- 1st half equation handles the sign `+/-`
- 2nd half handles the magnitude of the binning

> ```
> mawk '$NF = (-++_)^(+(__=$NF)<_) * ++_^(int(__+_--^-_)!=_--)'
> ```

```
X  -1.25  -2
X  -1.00  -2
X  -0.75  -2
X  -0.50  -2
X  -0.25  -2
X  0.00   -2
X  0.25   -2
X  0.50   -1
X  0.75   -1
X  1.00   1
X  1.25   1
X  1.50   2
X  1.75   2
X  2.00   2
X  2.25   2
X  2.50   2
```

==============================

this may not cover every possible scenario, but if u want a single liner to cover the samples shown :

> ```
> mawk '$NF = 4 < (_=int(2*$NF)-2)^2 ? 1+(-3)^(_<-_) :_'
> ```

```
A -1
B -1
C 2
D 2
```